# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure using IdentityServer3

Tags: authentication, certificate, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I am using the ThinkTecture IdentitySever3 in my Web Api project and it has been working fine for the past 2 months in the project I am developing. Suddenly as of today, I am running into this exception when I try to use authentication:

```
"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"
```

The project is using the idsrv3test.pfx that comes as a part of the IdentityServer3 samples.

Any ideas why it would suddenly start to behave like that? And how to fix it of course?

Comment: I had the same issue today. Required a repair of iisexpress 10

Comment: What kind of repair Mark ? Can you elaborate? 
@Mark

Comment: I finally found a working solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32788265/4660416](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32788265/4660416)

Comment: Go to programs and features in windows 10, select IIS Express 10 and select repair. This recreated the iis dev cert

Comment: Oh and yes as others have described, the cert is created under personal certs. You must copy to trusted root cert authorities' cert node in certificate management

Comment: You should manage/create/get your own certs and not use the sample PFX that comes with the samples. Doing so makes your application vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into very similar issues.

1. I had to go into MMC add the certificate plugin.
2. Find and remove all certificates with localhost.
3. Reboot
4. Go to programs and features in windows Search for IIS Express and select REPAIR
5. Reboot
6. Launch Visual studio 2015 Open my Application with IdentityServer in it. 
   Run it and accept the prompt in VS 2015 to add and trust the
   localhost cert.